# Scintilla.NET slow loading

Tags: .net, scintilla

I'm using Scintilla using the .NET wrapper, named Scintilla.NET. When creating an instance of it, i.e.:

```
   Dim c As New ScintillaNet.Scintilla
   Me.Controls.Add(c)
```

it takes almost a complete second to load the first time. Other times it is about 150 ms. Actually, this is not really acceptable in my situation as loading e.g. 10 files at once takes almost two seconds.

Is it true that Scintilla (or Scintilla.NET) is slow, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Scintilla, but maybe it's possible to not actually open the 10 files at once since they probably wouldn't be visible all at once anyway (I'm thinking there's a tabbed interface involved somewhere?), but rather load each of them when required (i.e. when the active tab changes to the one that represents that document). That's what I did in one of my apps recently, and arrived at a very fluent interface that loads its data 'lazily'. Of course, providing a 'loading' indicator also decreases the perceived time, even if the actual ms are the same or even larger.

Comment: It's indeed a tabbed editor. I'm not very keen on what you call lazy loading, but perhaps it is an interesting solution as you then spread the loading time over a longer period, instead of two seconds at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say that Scintilla is slow. If is slow only the first time you create the control, this might be because the Scintilla.dll is loaded then, and the 1 second you experience might be the time needed by the system to load the dll.

If this is the case, I suggest you load the dll (by creating a dummy control) when your application starts (on splash screen for example) - if this is acceptable in your scenario.

Comment: In fact, I'm already doing this. This resolves the first time loading, but all other instances cause a freeze time of ~150ms still. So when creating several controls at once, it is hanging my application for a rather long time.

Comment: In this case, 150 ms might be the time needed to instantiate the control so you don't have much to optimize in this case.